# Can I/O expanders be used to drive a Camera or LCD?

Tags: lcd, io, expander, drive

After searching around it seems that I/O expanders are used mostly to drive LEDs or buttons.

Could something more complicated like an LCD be driven without bit banging? I.e. are there typically libraries that do all the work?

Is this a typical use of I/O expanders?

An example I was thinking of was an ESP32 and OV2640 camera module with the pcf8575 I/O expander.

Comment: Plenty of hd44780 character lcds or Nokia lcds being ran off port expanders. But that's essentially bit banging.

Comment: I'd like to get some more clarification. What do you mean by driving a camera here? Sure, people use GPIO expanders over I2C and SPI buses to drive LCD modules. Yes they can be driven without bit-banging the GPIO expander pins, but GPIO expanders allow to draw less wires to front panel, like 4 for the whole panel instead of 7 for display and 1 for each LED and 1 for each button. And there are Arduino libraries for using LCD modules over IO expanders. Only thing compared to direct GPIO is slower speed.

Comment: @Justme I'm running low on GPIOs on my chip so wanting less wires from the camera module (typically they require around 15 which is too much in my case). My question is could I initialize, capture images etc with my camera easily via an I/O expander? I wonder if a special library has to be written. Or if I could simply do something like #define CAM_D0_PIN=expander.pins[0]

Comment: @JC2020 that would depend on the camera module of course, and what you expect from it. If it is even possible, don't expect a huge performance out of it. You should define which specific camera module you are talking about, so that all this is just not hand-waving and speculation.

Comment: @Justme thanks for your message. The camera module I had in mind was the OV2640

Comment: Unless your library is compatible with i2c and/or port expanders then no simply setting the d0 pin to an expander pin would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Running a camera with a data bandwidth of 30 to 360 megabits per second is totally out of reach for a GPIO expander running on a 400 kilobit bus, by 2 to 3 orders of magnitude.